# Customize woocommerce login & my account Page

Tags: wordpress

I am using woo commerce on my website.  
When i customize  **my account page**  , Same customization shows on **my login page**. 
Like if i add any word  to My account page , Same word Shows on Login Page
Are they using same php? 
How can i separate those two pages? 
   [My Website login page](http://www.cardmart.tk/?page_id=749)
Thanks

Comment: looks like they are on the same page??

Comment: Yes , with same page id

Comment: so you wanna create a new page is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, New registration/login page if it is possible or to separate my account and login page ,

Comment: can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On setup, woocommerce creates only 4 pages automatically, shop, cart, checkout and my account. to create a login page, go to pages>add new and you can customise it there.

Comment: you can copy your login in form from the current form but delete it from the current my account page. you will have to set up a redirect if you want it to redirect to the customers account

Comment: Ok , But how  would i create that login/registration window  & redirects it to my account page?

Comment: see here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woo-commerce-login-redirect for redirect instructions

Comment: I copied my login form to theme>woocommerce  then what to do next? how can i edit it as a page in wordpress?

Comment: okay thanks for redirection ? but what about login page? there is no separate shortcode by woocommerce , so that i can paste it in wordpress editor?